# Javascript/JQuery - Default 2 Radio Inputs Sharing Same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I've spent so much time trying to figure this out myself (hours and hours!) and I am slowly figuring it out but at this stage I could really do with some help.

Right now, I think the problem is that the radio button has a ID only so I cannot trigger both together.

**Objective:**

I need to default a specific radio input that exists in 2 forms on the same page. The radio button has the same ID in each form. I cannot change the code these forms use directly. I can only manipulate it with javascript or jquery.

Each form is wrapped in it's own unique div so I have tried to search and find the radio input in each unique div and trigger the click hoping both would be clicked but only one radio button is clicked.

Please see my JSFiddle Code below

```
//Form 1
<div id="tmp_order2step-70097"><input type="radio" id="pid-909272" 
name="purchase[product_id]" value="909272"></div>

//Form 2
<div id="tmp_order2step-70097-154"><input type="radio" id="pid-909272" 
name="purchase[product_id]" value="909272"></div>

//Trying to click Form 1's radio button
$(function () {
$(document.getElementById('tmp_order2step-70097')).find("#pid-
909272").trigger("click");
});

//Trying to click Form 2's radio button
$(function () {
$(document.getElementById('tmp_order2step-70097-154')).find("#pid-
909272").trigger("click");
});

Result - Only one radio button/input clicked.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0j5tyhq8/

Thank you for any help/advice with this!

UPDATE: Thanks for the advice. I cannot change radio names without breaking the code so I have started over and used one form which works fine of course.

Comment: So you want to set an event listener to those radio buttons? Also why do you have `document.getElementById()` in the jQuery selector? It doesn't make sense.... why not just use `#`

Comment: Radio buttons work by being exclusive.  If you want to be able to "select" both, they can't be the same radio button group.  Radio buttons are grouped by `name`.  ie all radio buttons with the same `name` are in the same group and you can only select one of them.  That's what makes them radio buttons.   If you want to be able to select both, change the name of one http://jsfiddle.net/0j5tyhq8/1/

Comment: Or change them to checkboxes.

Comment: Maybe changing the attributes is your best bet. Example `$('#tmp_order2step-70097').find("#pid-909272").attr('id','tmp_order2step-70097');` you could also change the name using this same method.